# Where to write Relay Command?

Tags: wpf, mvvm, relaycommand

I am trying to follow standard MSDN steps to form up MVVM architecture in WPF. My folders and class hierarchy are as below.

**Models**
   => FormModel.cs
**ViewModels**
   => MainViewModel.cs
   => ViewModelBase.cs
**Views**
   => MainView.xaml

and

=> App.xaml

Please consider these above all in standard approach.

Now I want to create RelayCommand method about which I don't have any idea. Can you please tell me where to put it? Should I create a separate Command folder? Or under any of above folders? Also give an example of RelayCommand if possible as I don't know how to implement RelayCommand method.

Comment: Are you also using Prism in your MVVM Application? Then you could use `DelegateCommand`

Comment: Not using any template

Comment: It should be in an MVVM package that contains the RelayCommand, ViewModelBase, Locator, ... so you can reuse it in othe rprojects.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would vote for ViewModels in this case - the implementation is only going to be used in ViewModel classes. I wouldn't create a Command folder, as it will sit in there on its own, but if you have similar constructs perhaps a Utilities folder?

Instead of reinventing the wheel, I use MVVMLight from Nuget (others are available) - has a RelayCommand implementation included, and can be used in portable class libraries (for store apps).

Comment: Utilities is a logic place to put it. You only need one implementation, copy/pasted from somewhere online.